# XAML To MXML Conversion

Tags: wpf, apache-flex, xaml, mxml

Is to possible to generate MXML file using XAML file and vice versa???

Both are based on xml and contains similar type of coding....

So is there a way to convert XAML file to MXML file and vice versa?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to convert it manually. No other possibilities!

Comment: For peopel like me: 

MXML is an XML-based user interface markup language first introduced by Macromedia in March 2004. Adobe Systems (which acquired Macromedia in December 2005) gives no official meaning for the acronym, but some developers suggest it should stand for "Magic eXtensible Markup Language" (which is a backronym).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, as even though XAML and MXML are both based on XML, and might look a bit the same, but XAML contains things such as attach properties, mark-up extensions, data binding, etc. which are the building blocks of XAML, and as I am aware is not present it MXML, so you can't translate one to another.

Answer (score 1):

if you want one you'll have to build one yourself using an XML parser and XML writer. by looking at the specification of each one you should be able to translate from  one to another heck you could make the converter in flash/flex itself after all they are still just XML and I've analyzed both XML structures aside from actionscript/.net scripting you could simply make a translator. heck i could make one. if i do I'll let you know